# Are CSS selectors without properties of any effect?

Tags: css

I got a maintenance job and there is a huge CSS file, in which I found a lot of things like the following:

```
.xxxx {}
```

That is, a selector with absolutely nothing in it. I think they are useless, but there are so many of them I start to doubt myself. Am I right that they can be removed safely? Or they actually are doing something and I should keep them?

Comment: **Yes** you can remove them it won't impact anything.

Comment: This thing does not do anything, this is just an unnecessary block of code, you _should_ remove it

Comment: this just makes the size of the file bigger. remove it!

Comment: Thanks guys! I'm confident now!

Comment: @Manwal, Tushar, Luthando... It's not 100% certain that it can be removed. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say it's probably the worst design in history (or a stronger contender to the title...) but it **could** be used.

See below:

```js
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.setProperty('color', 'red');
```

```css
.randomClass {}
```

```html
<div class="randomClass">No styling?</div>
```

You can acces, process, and even modify stylesheets. Even if a selector is empty of styles, that can be modified using code.

So, it's probably very safe to remove, but if you want to be 100% certain, either leave it there, or go through all possible code branches.

Comment: Very interesting! Fortunately I can be sure no code of that nature exists in my project.